# how to detect if my app is offline?

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem, I build a jQuerymobile application which uses the google maps javascript API.

The problem is, when I start the app in flight mode, I just see the loading bar:
[image]

How to check if the app is offline and then just show a message, that the map is not working offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For airplane mode specifically:

```
navigator.onLine
```

It's a boolean value so it can be used such as:

```
if(navigator.onLine) {
   //show full app
} else {
   //show offline message
}
```

There are events to listen for to handle transitions between online/offline states: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine

This does NOT work for detecting extremely low signals or no valid public internet routes. Those scenarios require other techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Offline.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline), an open-source library built for just this purpose.